# JuPyter: Creating Decision Tree, TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float''

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, decision-tree

I'm creating decision tree with JuPyter notebook and when I started creating the decision and putting the features and target class the jupyter give me this error that is found in this cell for  the decision tree.`dt = c.fit(X_train, y_train)`

This is the error.

```
TypeError                             

    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0f9186b7935c> in <module>()
----> 1 dt = c.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    788             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    789             check_input=check_input,
--> 790             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    791         return self
    792 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    138 
    139         if is_classification:
--> 140             check_classification_targets(y)
    141             y = np.copy(y)
    142 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     y : array-like
    168     """
--> 169     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    286         return 'continuous' + suffix
    287 
--> 288     if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
    289         return 'multiclass' + suffix  # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
    290     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    221     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    222     if axis is None:
--> 223         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    224     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    225         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    281         aux = ar[perm]
    282     else:
--> 283         ar.sort()
    284         aux = ar
    285     flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I'm confused because my data set feature is clean it is all Int and the target class in the only categorical.

Can someone tell me what is happening and what to do so that `dt = c.fit(X_train, y_train)` will work? `c = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=100)` c is a decision tree classifier.

This is my sample data set:
[image]

Comment: Try using label encoder on Courses column and then fit a tree.

Comment: I ran into a situation where the fit on a DecisionTreeClassifier ran successfully within Jupyter, then when I exported the Python code and ran that I got the above error only with str and int.